# How to recursively normalize my histogram count

Tags: histogram, multidimensional-scaling

I need to scale my histogram as I cannot store them with large numbers. Hence, I need to normalize it. I have taken normalization factor as sum of total population. But this need to happen recursively. As samples arrive, I need to count them and scale them iteratively. Any formula to iteratively update?

I have histogram both in 1D and 2D.

Will be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one naive approach, let me explain with an example:

Suppose we have a normalized histogram with just 3 bins (`hist[1]`, `hist[2]`, `hist[3]`). Let the size of the current population be 100. Then, a new value can be binned as follows :

The following is a pseudo-code :

```
update_hist (curr_population_size, hist, new_element) {

    bin_index = determine_bin_index (new_element);
    new_population_size = curr_population_size + 1;

    for i = 1 to number_of_bins(hist)
        if i == bin_index then
            hist[i] = (hist[i]*curr_population_size + 1)/new_population_size;
        else        
            hist[i] = (hist[i]*curr_population_size)/new_population_size;
    endfor

    return hist
}
```

Now Suppose, `hist[1] = 0.3`,`hist[2] = 0.2`, and `hist[3] = 0.5`. Then, by the above pseudo-code, a new value, when arrives, and whose bin is determined to be say 2, updates the `hist` as :

```
hist[1] = (0.3*100  )/101 = 0.3069306930693069
hist[2] = (0.2*100+1)/101 = 0.2079207920792079
hist[3] = (0.5*100  )/101 = 0.4950495049504950
```

A note of caution : Repeated multiplications and divisions with large numbers may result in erroneous values due to rounding errors introduced by floating point arithmetic.

Comment: I think this is pseudocode; that in itself is fine but please confirm; otherwise some readers may wonder whether some language is being used that they don't know. (If it's some particular language, the point is made for me.)

Comment: Please spell out the assumptions here. It seems that the bins are all supposed predefined.

Comment: @NickCox Yes it is pseudocode, I have updated my answer. Well yes, the number of bins is predefined here because, as the question only asks for updating an existing histogram, with new streaming incoming values.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Sometimes bins will be predictable in advance, but not always.